# How much damage does a backstab do?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

I was playing TF2 and I turned on a setting so I can see exactly what damage I am doing. I noticed after back stabbing a few enemies the number ranges from 100 to 1000. So why does the game say I am doing like 900 damage per kill... is this because it is an instant kil or what?

Comment: Spy backstabs are always meant to be one-hit kills on everyone, with few exceptions like dead ringer protected spies.

Comment: Also über charged people

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Backstabs deal 600% of the target's *current* health, as listed on [the Spy-cicle's wiki page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Spy-cicle). I believe this damage is the same as all knives' backstabs.  So killing an almost-dead scout will yield damage much lower than an overhealed heavy, but the intent is basically that no matter how much health your target is and no matter what ridiculous, unfeasible buffs they have, a backstab will instant kill them from damage alone (though a couple things like the Razorback can still save you).

Also note that, while spy backstabs are automatic crits, the damage they deal isn't "critical damage". Effects that block critical hits will not reduce backstab damage at all.

As listed on the item's page the Spy-cicle can do 34-46 damage with a frontal hit, but melee damage doesn't affect how much a backstab does.

Comment: Its also worth noting that the stab itself only does 2x the current heath of the person you stab, but because it will always deal critical hits, you can only deal the 6x current heath upon a backstab. Another thing to note is that bosses CANNOT be 1-hit killed by a backstab, regardless of the knife or location.